# Handling many to many relationship through a pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I asked a similar question earlier but have made a lot of changes since then and I have a different issue now.
I have changed my schemas to be like the following.

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('userName')->default('');
    $table->string('userEmail')->default('');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('user_groups', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('groupName')->default('');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});

Schema::create('users_user_groups', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();
});

Schema::table('users_user_groups', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('user_groups');
});
```

Essentially, a user can be apart of many user_groups, and user_groups can have many users.  So I am looking at a many to many relationship 
which is why I added the table users_user_groups.  I then set up my Models for these two like so

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'users_user_groups')->withPivot('user_id', 'group_id');
    }
}

class Group extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_groups';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function profusionUser()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'pusers_user_groups')->withPivot('user_id', 'group_id');
    }
}
```

I am pretty confident the above is set up correctly, to me it makes sense.  Now the work for this takes place in my UserController.  The core function is this
and I have tried to comment it to explain what is happening.

```
public function updateUsers()
{
    $users = Helper::returnUsersFromLdap();  //Get all users from Directory

    foreach($users as $userName => $userData) {
        $user = User::firstOrNew(['userName' => $userName]);  //Create user if needed

        foreach ($userData as $userEmail => $userDepartment) {
            $name = preg_replace('/@.*?$/', '', $userEmail);
            $user->userEmail = $userEmail;

            $userGroups = Helper::returnGroupsFromLdap($name); //Get all user_groups user is apart off

            foreach ($userGroups as $group) {
                $usGroup = new Group();  //Create the user_groups
                $usGroup->groupName = $group;
                $usGroup->save();
            }
            $user->save();
            $user->groups()->sync($userGroups);  //Link the users groups to the user
        }
    }

    return Redirect::route('users.index');
}
```

So my user_groups table is populated with data like so

```
+-----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| id  | groupName  | created_at          | updated_at          | deleted_at |
+-----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
|   1 | Group 1    | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | NULL       |
|   2 | Group 2    | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | NULL       |
|   3 | Group 3    | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | NULL       |
|   4 | Group 4    | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | NULL       |
|   5 | Group 1    | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | NULL       |
|   6 | Group 3    | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | NULL       |
|   7 | Group 2    | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | NULL       |
|   8 | Group 5    | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | NULL       |
|   9 | Group 1    | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | NULL       |
|  10 | Group 2    | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | NULL       |
|  11 | Group 1    | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | NULL       |
|  12 | Group 3    | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | 2016-05-20 15:55:34 | NULL       |
```

Now the first problem is that groups are being repeated in this table when I am not sure if they need to be?  If 2 users are in the same
group, two entries will be made above, one for each user.  Should I make this unique somehow?

Now my second problem is regarding my pivot table.  The output of this is like so

```
+-----+--------------------+
| id  | user_id | group_id |
+-----+--------------------+
|   1 |       1 |        0 |
|   2 |       1 |        0 |
|   3 |       1 |        0 |
|   4 |       2 |        0 |
|   5 |       2 |        0 |
|   6 |       3 |        0 |
|   7 |       3 |        0 |
|   8 |       3 |        0 |
|   9 |       3 |        0 |
```

So the user_id is being updated properly, and the correct number of times.  So I know that the user with the id 1 is in 3 groups.
However, for some reason, the group_id is not being updated.

Is there any reason this is not being updated properly?  Any suggestions appreciated and it would be good to get some input regarding the user_groups
table and whether this should contain unique group names.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the tables definition? Just to find out whether their structure is the one you think they are...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the use of that "profusion" table, but I think that this:

```
Schema::create('users_user_groups', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();
});
```

should be this:

```
Schema::create('users_user_groups', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('user_groups');
});
```

I mean, you have to specify the "foreign" part in your users_user_groups table, but somehow it ended up in the "profusion_whatever" table.

Answer (score 1):

> Is If 2 users are in the same group, two entries will be made above, one for each user. Should I make this unique somehow?

Yes, your user_groups table should have groups uniquely. It is the job of your pivot table to maintain the many-to-many relationship.

The reason that you have duplicate groups in user_groups is that the foreach loop that creates the groups is inside the foreach for users.

Instead of doing a direct database insert in that loop, construct an array inside the foreach(users) loop that holds groups.

```
$groupsArray[] = []; //define this outside the users foreach loop

//inside the users foreach loop
foreach ($userGroups as $group) {
    if(!array_key_exists($group, $groupsArray){
         $groupsArray[$group] = true;
    }
}

//then, outside the users foreach loop:
foreach($groupsArray as $group){
    $usGroup = new Group();  //Create the user_groups
    $usGroup->groupName = $group;
    $usGroup->save();
}
```